# Markerwithlabel library memory consumption issue on adding 5000 markers in map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, memory-leaks, google-maps-markers

Have done basic map where 5000 markers placed in it.

**Using google maps default marker:**

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.509, -105.348);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: latLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

for(i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
    });
    var lat = latLng.lat()
    ,       lng = latLng.lng()+0.005;
     latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeev140/wa3r9zp2/7/

Memory Usage: 48.8 MB

**Using Marker with Label:**

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.509, -105.348);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: latLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

for(i=0; i<5000; i++) {
    new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });

    var lat = latLng.lat()
    ,   lng = latLng.lng()+0.005;
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeev140/n0xhd38f/13/

Memory Usage: 279 MB

> Any idea how to resolve this memory consumption using marker with label?

Comment: How did you detect the leak(the consumption of more memory must not be the result of a memory-leak)

Comment: Using chrome dev tools profiles --> take snapshot

Comment: Sorry it is consumption of more memory, not a memory leak. I will edit my question

Comment: A `google.maps.Marker` basically isn't created based on single DOMNodes, but a MarkerWithLabel creates DOMNodes for the labels(1 for each Marker)....this of course will use more memory

Comment: I haven't passed any label content in  new MarkerWithLabel. Still consumption of memory is there or still it will create label?

Comment: The label will always be created and it uses 3 nodes for each label(labelDiv, eventDiv and crossDiv)

Comment: I have the same problem then finally decided to use google maps Marker instead with all the feature of MarkerWithLabel. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions